# Why in customtkinter I can't create 2 apps with a background

Tags: python, customtkinter

I I wanted to make 2 applications in 2 files so that I could run the second one from 1 application. But there is a problem: if a background image is placed in 1 application, then not work in 2. How can this be fixed? Here is an example of the code, the background is placed in the first and second window, work in first, but not work in the second.

```
import customtkinter as ctk
from PIL import Image

def start():
    App2()

class App1:
    icon1 = Image.open('res\\font33543543.jpg')
    font1 = ctk.CTkImage(icon1, size=(600, 400))

    def __init__(self):
        self.window1 = ctk.CTk()
        ctk.CTkLabel(self.window1, text='', image=self.font1).place(x=0, y=0)
        ctk.CTkButton(self.window1, command=start).place(x=10, y=10)
        self.window1.mainloop()

class App2:
    icon2 = Image.open('res\\font33543543.jpg')
    font2 = ctk.CTkImage(icon2, size=(600, 400))

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = ctk.CTk()
        ctk.CTkLabel(self.window, text='', image=self.font2).place(x=0, y=0)
        self.window.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App1()
```

When creating the second window, an error occurred:

> _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist

Comment: The issue is that when App2 is instantiated, it is trying to load the image again from disk but the file is already opened. You must have a copy of the image for the 2nd background if I'm not mistaken. Also, it is `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: I tried using a copy of the image or another images, but the error still remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have 2 main windows in your app.

You can fix it by using a `CTkToplevel` in the second window:

```
import customtkinter as ctk
from PIL import Image

def start():
    App2()

class App1:
    icon1 = Image.open('res\\font33543543.jpg')
    font1 = ctk.CTkImage(icon1, size=(600, 400))

    def __init__(self):
        self.window1 = ctk.CTk()
        ctk.CTkLabel(self.window1, text='', image=self.font1).place(x=0, y=0)
        ctk.CTkButton(self.window1, command=start).place(x=10, y=10)
        self.window1.mainloop()

class App2:
    icon2 = Image.open('res\\font33543543.jpg')
    font2 = ctk.CTkImage(icon2, size=(600, 400))

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = ctk.CTkToplevel()
        ctk.CTkLabel(self.window, text='', image=self.font2).place(x=0, y=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App1()
```